# ORA-04043 Error when oracle type is declared in a package

Tags: oracle, jdbc, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java - passing array in oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399750/java-passing-array-in-oracle-stored-procedure)

We have a package defining a type and a procedure which uses that type.

The problem is - If the type is defined in a package the call to create an java.sql.Array fails. If the type is declared outside the package everything works fine. The package is declared as

```
create or replace PACKAGE TEST_ARRAY AS 

   TYPE COLTYPE_NUMTAB is table of number;

   procedure Test_Procedure(some_var_name in COLTYPE_NUMTAB);

END TEST_ARRAY;
```

We use spring's stored procedure to call the above Test_Procedure

```
@Component
public class CustomStoredProcedureWithoutTypePackage extends StoredProcedure {
    private final String variable_name = "some_var_name";
    private final String typeName = "TEST_ARRAY.COLTYPE_NUMTAB";

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Autowired
    public CustomStoredProcedureWithoutTypePackage(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource, "TEST_ARRAY.Test_Procedure1");
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(variable_name, Types.ARRAY, typeName));
        compile();
    }


    public void executeSP() {
        Map<String, Object> inputParameter = Maps.newHashMap();
        inputParameter.put(variable_name, createArray(typeName, new Object[] {1, 2, 3}));
        Map<String, Object> outputMap = execute(inputParameter);
        System.out.println(outputMap);
    }

    private Array createArray(final String typeName, final Object[] values) {
        return jdbcTemplate.execute(new ConnectionCallback<Array>() {
            @Override
            public Array doInConnection(Connection con) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                OracleConnection oracleCon = (OracleConnection) con.unwrap(Connection.class);
                return oracleCon.createARRAY(typeName, values);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Is there are any specific style/way of declaring the type when it's declared in a package?

Comment: See [java - passing array in oracle stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1399750/119634), it's not possible to reference package types from java.