# Record type reflection / populating a record variable of an unknown type (PL/SQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a package with a record type and a variable of that type in it:

```
CREATE PACKAGE my_package AS
  TYPE t_rec IS RECORD(
    id           NUMBER,
    name         VARCHAR2(100),
    last_updated DATE
  );
  v_var t_rec;
END;
```

I want to create an universal procedure for populating any record variable, so it can be called like this:

```
BEGIN
  populate_record('my_package.v_var', 'MY_TABLE', CHARTOROWID(:VAR1));
END;
```

The logic of that procedure may look like this:

```
PROCEDURE populate_record(
  p_var_name   IN VARCHAR2,
  p_table_name IN VARCHAR2,
  p_rowid      IN ROWID
) IS
BEGIN
  -- determining a type of a given record variable
  -- determining names and data types of given record variable's columns
  -- selecting a row from a given table by a given rowid
  -- filling out a given record variable by mapping table columns
  --   to record columns by their names (using dynamic PL/SQL)
END;
```

But I have no idea how to obtain information about a given record. Are there any data dictionary views or built-in functions for querying record type columns?
Thanks.

P.S.: 11.2

UPDATED

I found a way to obtain info about records using PL/Scope:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW user_record_types AS
SELECT
  i.object_name package_name,
  i.name type_name
FROM
  user_identifiers i
WHERE
  i.object_type = 'PACKAGE'
  AND i.type = 'RECORD'
  AND i.usage = 'DECLARATION'
/

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW user_record_types_columns AS
SELECT
  i1.object_name package_name,
  i1.name type_name,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY
      i1.object_name,
      i1.name
    ORDER BY
      i2.usage_id
  ) column_num,
  i2.name column_name,
  i3.name column_type,
  i3.type column_type_class
FROM
  user_identifiers i1,
  user_identifiers i2,
  user_identifiers i3
WHERE
  i1.object_type = 'PACKAGE'
  AND i1.type = 'RECORD'
  AND i1.usage = 'DECLARATION'
  AND i2.object_name = i1.object_name
  AND i2.object_type = i1.object_type
  AND i2.type = 'VARIABLE'
  AND i2.usage = 'DECLARATION'
  AND i2.usage_context_id = i1.usage_id
  AND i3.object_name = i2.object_name
  AND i3.object_type = i2.object_type
  AND i3.usage = 'REFERENCE'
  AND i3.usage_context_id = i2.usage_id
/

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW user_record_variables AS
SELECT
  i1.object_name package_name,
  i1.name variable_name,
  CASE i2.type
    WHEN 'RECORD' THEN
      i2.object_name
    WHEN 'PACKAGE' THEN
      i2.name
  END type_package_name,
  CASE i2.type
    WHEN 'RECORD' THEN
      i2.name
    WHEN 'PACKAGE' THEN
      i3.name
  END type_name
FROM
  user_identifiers i1,
  user_identifiers i2,
  user_identifiers i3
WHERE
  i1.object_type = 'PACKAGE'
  AND i1.type = 'VARIABLE'
  AND i1.usage = 'DECLARATION'
  AND i2.object_name = i1.object_name
  AND i2.object_type = i1.object_type
  AND i2.type IN ('RECORD', 'PACKAGE')
  AND i2.usage = 'REFERENCE'
  AND i2.usage_context_id = i1.usage_id
  AND i3.object_name (+) = i2.object_name
  AND i3.object_type (+) = i2.object_type
  AND i3.type (+) = 'RECORD'
  AND i3.usage (+) = 'REFERENCE'
  AND i3.usage_context_id (+) = i2.usage_id
/
```

But there is a problem when I use %ROWTYPEs, because there is no info about "what of" that %ROWTYPE is. So I think that PL/Scope is not a complete solution...

Comment: Instead of using records - Try using [objects](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjint.htm)

Comment: I can't. I gave you just an example, but there is a vast amount of code already written (it is impossible to rewrite that all). I need to implement this over existing code.

Comment: How dynamic does this need to be?  You should be able to use something like Emmanuel's answer to dynamically build a package.  (But that would probably be a complicated task involving hierarchical queries.)  But even that would still require you to re-generate the code.  AFAIK there is no truly dynamic way to inspect and update a package variable, since dynamic PL/SQL will not have access to your session-level data.

Comment: Why not?
`DECLARE
  v_var_name VARCHAR2(100) := 'my_package.v_var';
  v_col_name VARCHAR2(100) := 'id';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
    BEGIN
      ' || v_var_name || '.' || v_col_name || ' := 1;
    END;
  ';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(my_package.v_var.id);
END;`

Comment: Woops, you're right.  Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: You could create a dependency to dynamically find the attributes of a rowtype.  For example, if my_package.v_var was a %rowtype, you could `create package temp_package is temp_var my_package.v_var%type; end;`.  Then use `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` to find which table it is dependent on.  Join that to `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` to get the attribute names, which must be the same as the column names.

Comment: But if you know the table name, do you even need PL/SQL reflection at all?  It seems like one way or another the record must have the same column names as the table for this to ever really work.  Then you only need ALL_TAB_COLUMNS to create the dynamic PL/SQL assignments.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use table `user_identifiers` or `all_identifiers` if you have the access, as [this other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410522/discover-pl-sql-package-level-types-using-oracle-dictionary-views) post shows.

You may need to recompile your packages:

```
alter package  my_types compile plscope_settings='IDENTIFIERS:ALL' reuse settings;
```

Unfortunately this is only available from 11gR1.

Comment: I queried this view by MY_PACKAGE and I have found four variables there: V_VAR, ID, NAME, and LAST_UPDATED. Obviously, last three variables are parts of V_VAR. But how can I know this?

Comment: No, there is no such a reference. I see only `USAGE_CONTEXT_ID` which is actually points to `T_REC` type declaration, but not `V_VAR` variable (there can be many variables of such a type, I can't take just a first one).

Comment: I think you speak in terms of LINES returned by the view (4 lines then) where I'm speaking in terms of COLUMNS. The view `user_identifiers` contains several columns: OWNER, NAME, SIGNATURE, TYPE and others. I'm talking about the data in the TYPE column: it can be either PACKAGE, PROCEDURE, or RECORD (among many others) - I think you need this last one.