# Generating JDBC code for Oracle PL/SQL package

Tags: java, jdbc, plsql, code-generation

I have a large Oracle PL/SQL package with several procedures with IN and OUT type parameters. And several of these parameters are User defined Types. Some of them are Types defined in the same package. (Defined package Specification).

Is there a easy way to Generate Java code directly from Oracle Package that can be used to call these procedures via JDBC?

Comment: If it really is just "several" procedures, why is this not practical to do by hand, quickly?

Comment: @IraBaxter The Oracle Packages I am receiving are to be decommissioned soon. Currently we need to build a quick web tool as a temporary interface to see how they return results. So any amount I spend is not going to be useful later. Also, I am wondering if I can get away from writing 100+ lines of code(to convert java objects into Oracle understandable Objects) to make calls to Oracle procedures? I feel it is absolutely over head.

Answer (score 2):

First off, up until Oracle 11g, package types cannot be discovered easily via Oracle's dictionary views, and they're rather hard to serialise / deserialise over JDBC. If you want to support package types in stored procedures from Java, a good idea might be to write bridge methods that wrap / unwrap the package types in SQL `TABLE` / `VARRAY` / `OBJECT` types instead. More info here:

- [Discover PL/SQL package-level types using Oracle dictionary views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410522/discover-pl-sql-package-level-types-using-oracle-dictionary-views)
- [Fetch Oracle table type from stored procedure using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410452/fetch-oracle-table-type-from-stored-procedure-using-jdbc)

### Writing such a code generator yourself:

In order to write a source code generator for all the packages and standalone routines (procedures / functions), and all the `TABLE` / `VARRAY` / `OBJECT` types that might be involved, you'll have to query the following dictionary views:

**Packages**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE'
```

**Standalone routines**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE')
```

**Package routines**

(Watch for overloaded routines and other caveats)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ALL_OBJECTS o
JOIN ALL_PROCEDURES p ON o.OWNER = p.OWNER AND o.OBJECT_NAME = p.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE o.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE'
```

**Routine arguments**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ALL_ARGUMENTS
```

**`TABLE` / `VARRAY` types**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ALL_COLL_TYPES
WHERE COLL_TYPE IN ('VARYING ARRAY', 'TABLE')
```

**`OBJECT` types**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ALL_TYPES
WHERE TYPECODE = 'OBJECT'
```

**`OBJECT` attributes**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ALL_TYPE_ATTRS
```

Using the above information, you can generate the necessary source code taking into account the following features:

- `OUT` parameters need to be registered with their appropriate [`java.sql.Types`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html) type to a [`CallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html).
- `OBJECT` types have to be registered in a specific type mapping with each bind variable
- `OBJECT` types should be generated as [`java.sql.SQLData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLData.html).
- In case you're using object-oriented PL/SQL (`MEMBER PROCEDURES` on `OBJECT` types, preferably make use of the non-OO syntax passing the `OBJECT` value as the `SELF` argument).
- `TABLE` and `VARRAY` type references have to be created using ojdbc's `createARRAY()` API.
- Special care needs to be taken when nesting `OBJECT` and `TABLE` / `VARRAY` types, there are numerous caveats, especially when `BLOB` or `CLOB` values are involved.
- `REF CURSOR` types need to be taken into account.
- Overloaded procedures in packages are best disambiguated by using PL/SQL named parameter syntax.

### Using a third-party library

You could use [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), a commercial library which provides native support for all of the above. (Disclaimer: I work the company behind jOOQ) A typical example would look like this:

```sql
CREATE TYPE FILM_T AS OBJECT (
  film_id int,
  title VARCHAR(255)
);
/
CREATE TYPE FILMS_T AS TABLE OF FILM_T;
/
CREATE TYPE CUSTOMER_T AS OBJECT (
  customer_id INT,
  first_name VARCHAR(45),
  last_name VARCHAR(45)
);
/
CREATE TYPE CUSTOMER_RENTAL_HISTORY_T AS OBJECT (
  customer CUSTOMER_T,
  films FILMS_T
);
/
CREATE PACKAGE RENTALS AS
  FUNCTION GET_CUSTOMER_RENTAL_HISTORY(p_customer CUSTOMER_T) 
  RETURN CUSTOMER_RENTAL_HISTORY_T;
END RENTALS;
/
```

Using jOOQ, you could then call the `RENTALS.GET_CUSTOMER_RENTAL_HISTORY` function as follows:

```java
CustomerRentalHistoryTRecord result =
  Rentals.getCustomerRentalHistory(config, new CustomerTRecord(1, "John", "Wayne"))

for (FilmTRecord film : result.getFilms()) {
  System.out.println(film.getTitle());
}
```