# Oracle - Select in sys views relation between table type (collection) and object

Tags: sql, oracle, select, types

It is possible select all user defined types in oracle from view sys.all_types. Also it is possible to select all type attributes from sys.all_type_attrs.

Still, I can't find a way to select or find relationship between table types and specific object types.

For example, `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "VARCHAR2_TT" AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000)` is defined table type. How can I use select to find out type of `VARCHAR2_TT`?

I do need it to generate procedures to print table types as varchar2.

Answer (score 3):

Once you know it's a collection (which `all_types` tells you), you can look at [the `all_coll_types` view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1044.htm):

> ALL_COLL_TYPES describes all named collection types (varrays and nested tables) accessible to the current user.

In this case you'd see, picking a couple of columns:

```
select coll_type, elem_type_name, length from all_coll_types where type_name = 'VARCHAR2_TT';

COLL_TYPE                      ELEM_TYPE_NAME                     LENGTH
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
TABLE                          VARCHAR2                             2000
```

For other types of collections some of the other columns will be relevant.

If you had a collection of objects you'd see the object type instead; here as a varray rather than a nested table, just to show the upper bound is available too:

```
create or replace type my_obj_t as object(id number);
/
create or replace type my_obj_tt as varray(5) of my_obj_t;
/

select coll_type, upper_bound, elem_type_name, length from all_coll_types where type_name = 'MY_OBJ_TT';

COLL_TYPE                      UPPER_BOUND ELEM_TYPE_NAME                     LENGTH
------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------ ----------
VARYING ARRAY                            5 MY_OBJ_T
```

... and so on.

You can also get the DDL to recreate the type with `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TYPE', 'VARCHAR2_TT') from dual` but that doesn't seem to be what you want here.

Comment: Isn't it should be USER_COLL_TYPES rather than ALL_COLL_TYPE for current user's schema.

Comment: The question refers to `all_types` so I stuck with that. But yes, if you're only working within one schema, `user_coll_types` would be fine.

Comment: I've included an example with a UDT too; the OP's table type *is* a UDT, but I assume you mean a table of other UDT, which I've done as a really simple object (the OP also referred to "relationship between table types and specific object types").

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need! I will just add all_type_attrs, to get all attributes from object.

Comment: Maybe you can also tell me in which table I can find types that is defined inside packages, if it is possible?

Comment: @Martins - if you're on 11g or higher you can see them in `user_identifiers`; you may need to [explicitly turn on tracking](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6413976/266304) though.

Comment: Thanks again! Managed to create a procedures that create printing functions that prints types and table types as varchar2.

Answer (score 0):

The below is the procedure to display all "table types" as "varchar2" in current user's schema. Ofcourse you can replace these user tables to ALL or DBA for broader prospects.

```
Create or replace procedure display_type 
as
    cursor type_usrr is 
    select UT.type_name typname
    from user_types  UT,
         user_COLL_TYPES UCT
    where UT.type_name = UCT.type_name
    and UT.typecode = 'COLLECTION'
    and UCT.COLL_TYPE = 'TABLE'
    and UCT.ELEM_TYPE_NAME = 'VARCHAR2' ;

Begin

for recs in type_usrr
loop
dbms_output.put_line(recs.typname);
end loop;

end;
```

Comment: The question is asking how to find the element type for a given collection; this is doing the reverse, starting with a known type and finding all matching collections types. Why use a procedure for this, rather than just running the cursor query directly? The join is also a bit pointless, you can just query `user_coll_types` on its own for this.

Comment: Question has 2 parts . First how to.find element type. You answered it very well. Second creating a procedure for the same. Check the last line." I do need it to generate proceedures to print table types as varchar2"

Comment: Mmm, I read that as printing the type of any table as a string, rather than restricting to tables of varchar2(n), as the rest of the question is about objects. It isn't clear though...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! First answer is more closer to what I need, but for me most important was to find out relationship between table type and type.