# How to specify IN parameter that as Oracle data type of TABLE type?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g

Based on this previous question on stackoverflow:

[Fetch Oracle table type from stored procedure using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410452/fetch-oracle-table-type-from-stored-procedure-using-jdbc)

The answer gave us a sample of OUT parameter using Oracle getArray and java.sql.Datum. But what if I want to specify IN parameter that has data type of Oracle TABLE type?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE XXINV.XX_PROD_SRCH_RSLT_REC_TYPE IS OBJECT(

item_no                   VARCHAR2(30),  
inventory_item_id         NUMBER,  
organization_id           NUMBER,  
item_description          VARCHAR2(240),  
item_long_description     VARCHAR2(240), 
cat_description           VARCHAR2(240),  
category_set_name         VARCHAR2(240),  
nla_flag                  VARCHAR2(1),  
CONSTRUCTOR  FUNCTION XX_PROD_SRCH_RSLT_REC_TYPE RETURN SELF AS RESULT , 
MEMBER PROCEDURE log_prod_srch_rslt_rec_values (SELF  IN  XX_PROD_SRCH_RSLT_REC_TYPE) )

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE xxinv.XX_PROD_SRCH_RSLT_TAB_TYPE AS TABLE OF XX_PROD_SRCH_RSLT_REC_TYPE;
```

And my SP is this:

```
XX_PART_RESEARCH_PKG .GET_PARTS
   (p_called_from          IN     VARCHAR2,
    p_item_id              IN     NUMBER,
    p_category_id          IN     NUMBER,
    p_mnfg_part_id         IN     NUMBER,
    p_item_desc            IN     VARCHAR2,
    p_include_NLA_items    IN     VARCHAR2,
    p_catl_group_id        IN     NUMBER,
    p_catl_attributes      IN     XX_PROD_ATTR_TAB_TYPE,
    x_srch_rslt            IN    XX_PROD_SRCH_RSLT_TAB_TYPE,
    x_return_status        OUT    VARCHAR2,
    x_returb_msg           OUT    VARCHAR2
   )
```

where as the XX_PROD_ATTR_TAB_TYPE is a table as IN parameter.

How to specify this in Java? I'm using Oracle 10g release 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your type has a constructor defined, I am not sure if this will work exactly, but I have posted samples on how to do this over on my blog. First, how to pass a record type into Oracle from Java:

http://betteratoracle.com/posts/31-passing-record-types-between-oracle-and-java

And then extended it to pass arrays of records into Oracle from Java:

http://betteratoracle.com/posts/32-passing-arrays-of-record-types-between-oracle-and-java

Comment: is passing array of records equals to TABLE of record? please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, when you have a type defined as "my_type is table of X" then it is effectively an array. To pass in a table (or array) or records, you build up an array in Java and then cast it into the Oracle internal type.