# ORA-03115: unsupported network data type or representation

Tags: java, oracle, procedure

Before issuing this question, i have googled a while, however now result found. My code attempts to call a procedure in oracle package(i am not very familiar with oracle package), and always get "ORA-03115: 不支持的网络数据类型或表示法", in english it should be 'unsupported network data type or representation'.

Below is my packagke:

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE PKG_ACTIVITY_REPORT 
IS
    TYPE activity_report_item_type IS RECORD
    ( emp_id MERCHANT.merchant_id%TYPE,
    emp_name MERCHANT.MERCHANT_NAME%TYPE,
    emp_gender MERCHANT.MERCHANT_CODE%TYPE );
    TYPE activity_report_items_type IS TABLE OF activity_report_item_type INDEX BY     BINARY_INTEGER;

    -- Procedure to retrive the activity report of given operator
    PROCEDURE enquiry_activity_report(activity_report_items OUT activity_report_items_type);
END PKG_ACTIVITY_REPORT;

create or replace 
PACKAGE BODY PKG_ACTIVITY_REPORT 
IS
PROCEDURE enquiry_activity_report (activity_report_items OUT activity_report_items_type)
IS
    activity_report_item activity_report_item_type;
BEGIN
    activity_report_item.emp_id := 300000000;
    activity_report_item.emp_name := 'Barbara';
    activity_report_item.emp_gender := 'Female';

    activity_report_items(1) := activity_report_item;

    activity_report_item.emp_id := 300000008;
    activity_report_item.emp_name := 'Rick';
    activity_report_item.emp_gender := 'Male';

    activity_report_items(2) := activity_report_item;

    FOR i IN 1..activity_report_items.count LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('i='||i||', emp_id ='||activity_report_items(i).emp_id||', emp_name ='
        ||activity_report_items(i).emp_name||', emp_gender = '||activity_report_items(i).emp_gender);
    END LOOP;
END enquiry_activity_report;

END PKG_ACTIVITY_REPORT;
```

I wanna return a array from the procedure, and call this procedure from java:

```
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        String storedProc = "{call pkg_activity_report.enquiry_activity_report(?)}";
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(storedProc);
        // register output parameter
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);
        cs.execute();
        Array array = cs.getArray(1);
        System.out.println(array);
        cs.close();
```

when run it, the exception thrown out. How do I map the OUT parameter to a java type? Pls help.

NOTE: when run this procedure from oracle sqldeveloper, it works properly.

```
DECLARE
  ACTIVITY_REPORT_ITEMS RAMON.PKG_ACTIVITY_REPORT.ACTIVITY_REPORT_ITEMS_TYPE;
BEGIN

  PKG_ACTIVITY_REPORT.ENQUIRY_ACTIVITY_REPORT(
    ACTIVITY_REPORT_ITEMS => ACTIVITY_REPORT_ITEMS
  );
END;
```

DBMS outputs the result:

```
i=1, emp_id =300000000, emp_name =Barbara, emp_gender = Female
i=2, emp_id =300000008, emp_name =Rick, emp_gender = Male
```

Comment: Try updating your JDBC driver to match your Oracle Database version.

Comment: Same, my oracle server and jdbc driver are both 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: Using PLSQL package level types in arrays is apparently a bit involved, you may want to use [JPublisher](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b10983/intro.htm#i1008445) to generate mappings. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410452/fetch-oracle-table-type-from-stored-procedure-using-jdbc) also has some info.

Answer (score 1):

Now I created 2 schema-level type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE activity_report_item_type AS OBJECT( 
emp_id NUMBER,
emp_name VARCHAR2(30),
emp_gender VARCHAR2(30) 
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE activity_report_items_type AS TABLE OF activity_report_item_type;
```

And move PROCEDURE enquiry_activity_report out of package, make it independently, then call it from java successfully.

```
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        String storedProc = "{call enquiry_activity_report(?)}";
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(storedProc);
        // register output parameter
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "ACTIVITY_REPORT_ITEMS_TYPE");
        cs.execute();
        Array array = cs.getArray(1);
        ResultSet rs = array.getResultSet();
        while (rs.next()) {
            // why getObject(2) instead of getObject(1)?
            Object elements[] = ((STRUCT) rs.getObject(2)).getAttributes();
            System.out.println(elements[0]);
            System.out.println(elements[1]);
            System.out.println(elements[2]);
        }

        cs.close();
```

If I put type declaration and procedure in package, java code will throw exception inform that 'no type definition found of "ACTIVITY_REPORT_ITEMS_TYPE".

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?