# Calling oracle procedure from java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, callable-statement

Following is my pl\sql and java usage:

**PL\SQL:**

```
procedure getDetails(id in number,
                       varArray out var_array,
                       valArray out var_array,
                       anotherArray out var_array,
                       description out varchar2   )

type var_array IS table of VARCHAR2(255) index by BINARY_INTEGER;
```

**Java:**

```
CallableStatement cstmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{call  pkg.getDetails(?,?,?,?,?)}");
    cstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(resultList.get(0).trim()));
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.ARRAY);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.ARRAY);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.ARRAY);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(5, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        cstmt.execute();
```

i am getting **error** at execute call:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETDETAILS'

Comment: See [Fetch Oracle table type from stored procedure using JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410452/fetch-oracle-table-type-from-stored-procedure-using-jdbc)

Comment: @vincent i would have marked as accepted if you have answered my question. Anyhow one clarification i need. You say PLSQL types cant be accessed from java. but table of varchar2 defined globally outside a stored procedure can be accessed by java, and only those types defined inside stored procedures cant be accessed right now.  am i right?

Comment: Yes, SQL objects (created separately from the procedure/package) can be accessed by java. PL/SQL types (created in a package) can't be accessed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I would like to add in that methods in OracleCallableStatement - registerIndexTableOutParameter(), getOraclePlsqlIndexTable() can be useful is retrieving PLSQL types(except table of records). But it requires OCI driver(really donno what is that) and will not work in classes12.jar(thin driver?). I am using classes12.jar  and i dont want to risk breaking someone else's code by replacing that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this code just with a copy paste, you only needs to change your own procedure and defines your parameters...

```
String sql = "{call my_own_procedure(?)}";
String[] values = new String[1];
values[0] = "some value";
java.sql.CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
callableStatement = myOracleConnection.prepareCall(sql);
if (values != null) {
  for (int parameterIndex = 0; parameterIndex < values.length; parameterIndex++) {
    callableStatement.setString(parameterIndex + 1, values[parameterIndex]);
  }
}
result = callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Don't forget to use SQL exceptions and import the SQL package...