# Getting pl/sql array of struct from stored procedure using JdbcSimpleCall

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbc

im trying to execute oracle stored procedure using SimpleJDBCCall, all tables and stored procedures are in restaurant schema, table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF
(
    STAFF_ID             NUMBER(5),
    STAFF_FIRST_NAME     VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)        NOT NULL,
    STAFF_LAST_NAME      VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)        NOT NULL,
    STAFF_ROLE           VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)        NOT NULL,
    STAFF_OTHER_DETAILS  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
);
```

my type package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Staff_Types 
AS
    TYPE Staff_Collection IS TABLE OF Staff%ROWTYPE;  
END Staff_Types;
```

my access package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Staff_TAPI 
AS
    FUNCTION getAllStaff RETURN Staff_Types.Staff_Collection;
END Staff_TAPI;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Staff_Tapi
AS
    FUNCTION getAllStaff 
        RETURN Staff_Types.Staff_Collection
    IS
        all_staff Staff_Types.Staff_Collection;
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        BULK COLLECT INTO all_staff
        FROM Staff;

        RETURN all_staff;
    END;

END Staff_Tapi;
```

Java Access:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("staffJdbcDAO")
public class StaffJDBCDAO implements StaffDAO {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    SimpleJdbcCall getAllMembersSP;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        initializeStoredProceduresCalls();
    }

    private void initializeStoredProceduresCalls() {
        getAllMembersSP = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
        getAllMembersSP.withCatalogName("Staff_Tapi");
        getAllMembersSP.withFunctionName("getAllStaff");
        getAllMembersSP.declareParameters(
            new SqlOutParameter("return",
                    Types.OTHER,
                    "Staff_Types.Staff_Collection",
                    new SqlReturnStructArray<>( new StaffMapper() )
            )
        );
        getAllMembersSP.compile();

    }

    @Override
    public List<Staff> getAllMembers() {
        Staff[] staff = getAllMembersSP.executeFunction(Staff[].class,new   HashMap<String,Object>() );
        return Arrays.asList(staff);
    }
}
```

mapping class:

```
public class StaffMapper implements StructMapper<Staff> {

    @Override
    public STRUCT toStruct(Staff staff, Connection connection, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        StructDescriptor descriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(typeName, connection);

        Object[] attributes = new Object[5];
        attributes[0] = new Integer( staff.getId() );
        attributes[1] = new String("STAFF_FIRST_NAME");
        attributes[2] = new String("STAFF_LAST_NAME");
        attributes[3] = new String("STAFF_ROLE");
        attributes[4] = new String("STAFF_OTHER_DETAILS");
        Struct staffStruct = connection.createStruct(typeName,attributes);
        return new STRUCT(descriptor,connection,attributes);
    }

    @Override
    public Staff fromStruct(STRUCT struct) throws SQLException {
        StructDescriptor descriptor = struct.getDescriptor();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = descriptor.getMetaData();
        Object[] attributes = struct.getAttributes();
        Map<String,Object> attributeMap = new HashMap<>();
        int idx = 1;
        for ( Object attribute : attributes )
            attributeMap.put( metaData.getColumnName(idx++),attribute );


        int id = ((Integer)attributeMap.get("STAFF_ID")).intValue();
        String firstName = (String) attributeMap.get("STAFF_FIRST_NAME");
        String lastName = (String) attributeMap.get("STAFF_LAST_NAME");
        String staffRole = (String) attributeMap.get("STAFF_ROLE");
        String otherDetails = (String) attributeMap.get("STAFF_OTHER_DETAILS");
        return new Staff(id,firstName,lastName,staffRole,otherDetails);
    }
}
```

and staff:

```
public class Staff {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String profession;
    private String otherDetails;


    public Staff(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String profession, String otherDetails) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.otherDetails = otherDetails;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // and others getters and setters
}
```

when i execute getAllMembers from StaffDAO im constatly getting :
    CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL 
        [{? = call   STAFF_TAPI.GETALLSTAFF()}]; 
        SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type: 1111;

when i change return type parameter to Types.Array i get:
    CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL
        [{? = call    STAFF_TAPI.GETALLSTAFF()}]; 
    SQL state [99999]; error code [17074];
        invalid name pattern:  restaurant.Staff_Types.Staff_Collection;

i tried in both ways with pattern "Staff_Types.Staf_collection" getting same results, im trying to do this for nearly 2 days without any idea what should i do, if anyone has any suggestions i will be greateful.

Comment: I seem to recall not being able to reference package types through jdbc and having to explicitly use `CREATE TYPE` (schema object) in order to reference. I think the data dictionary shows the package type names to be some mangled version of the name.  But I haven't used Oracle for a few years, so I may be out to lunch on this.

Comment: Thank you Glenn for quick answer. I tried this but the result is exactly the same as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load a PL/SQL `record` from a stored procedure through JDBC. In fact, you cannot even load such a type from Oracle SQL. See also this question for details:

- [Fetch Oracle table type from stored procedure using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410452/fetch-oracle-table-type-from-stored-procedure-using-jdbc)

You can only load SQL types through JDBC (as opposed to PL/SQL types). Given your example, you'll need to write:

```sql
-- You cannot really avoid this redundancy
CREATE TYPE STAFF AS OBJECT
(
    STAFF_ID             NUMBER(5),
    STAFF_FIRST_NAME     VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)        NOT NULL,
    STAFF_LAST_NAME      VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)        NOT NULL,
    STAFF_ROLE           VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)        NOT NULL,
    STAFF_OTHER_DETAILS  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
);
CREATE TYPE STAFF_TABLE AS TABLE OF STAFF;
```

And then:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Staff_TAPI 
AS
    FUNCTION getAllStaff RETURN STAFF_TABLE;
END Staff_TAPI;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to easily integrate your PL/SQL call, and since it is already built as a function: have you thought about something like this?

```
select * from TABLE(CAST(Staff_Tapi.getAllStaff() as Staff_Types.Staff_Collection))
```

This way, you can execute it easily as a regular JDBC query.  Once done, just process the `ResultSet` it returns with some minor variant of your `fromStruct` method in order to return a `List<Staff>` list to whatever business logic you have on top of it.  Hope you find this useful!

Comment: i tried your query and 
    select * from table(STAFF_TAPI.GETSTAFFFIRSTNAMES  ) and for each i got [Error] Execution ORA-00902: invalid datatype , but thanks for suggestion

Comment: Maybe the query I suggested you was casting to the wrong data type, I admit I have not an Oracle environment right now to test it.  However, I suggest you to try and make it work since it can be useful to you.  Have a look at table(cast ...) syntax in case that I had made some error with it:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm

Comment: Syntax is probably correct,from my investigation to do this with cast function the type you cast to , must be correct sql type,not pl/sql. And that leads to the problem that it(type) has to be in public scope(not in package) as far as i understand. I could make object type of staff_collection but then i have to create all staff columns in this object type. I hope it is undertandable ,english is not my native language;p Beside this, thanks for suggestions.

Comment: In the worst case, as you say, it would make you create the collection type in Oracle as a public collection of an object type repeating the table structure... may be the lesser evil?  Since it would probably make work your first Java implementation too

Comment: First of all thank you Jorge for all comments and time. Secondly ,the reason im seeking other solution is that , when im getting stored procedure result as query ,it cant do any DML statements what reduces possible use cases SP could provide.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to capitalize your custom type in java code like

```
    getAllMembersSP.declareParameters(
        new SqlOutParameter("return",
                Types.OTHER,
                "STAFF_TYPES.STAFF_COLLECTION",
                new SqlReturnStructArray<>( new StaffMapper() )
        )
    );
```