# Retrieving Oracle ADT / User Type metadata from JDBC

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, out-parameters

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410452/fetch-oracle-table-type-from-stored-procedure-using-jdbc) regarding how to retrieve/write Oracle Table Types from JDBC, is it possible to retrieve either the type metadata directly, or just the name of the type (which can then be combined with the Oracle driver's [StructDescriptor](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/StructDescriptor.html) to get the required data)?

Specifically, given this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE andrew_test (
      p_in_num_param          IN NUMBER
    , p_in_char_param         IN VARCHAR2
    , p_in_date_param         IN DATE
    , p_in_adt_param          IN sw_ty_number_array
    , p_out_num_param         OUT NUMBER
    , p_out_char_param        OUT VARCHAR2
    , p_out_date_param        OUT DATE
    , p_out_adt_param         OUT sw_ty_number_array
    , p_inout_num_param    IN OUT NUMBER
    , p_inout_char_param   IN OUT VARCHAR2
    , p_inout_date_param   IN OUT DATE
    , p_inout_adt_param    IN OUT sw_ty_number_array
) AS
BEGIN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

And this Java code (assume ParameterMetadata is just a POJO):

```java
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
DatabaseMetaData metadata = conn.getMetaData();
rs = metadata.getProcedureColumns(packageName, this.schemaName, procedureName, null);

while(rs.next()) {
    ProcedureParameter param = new ProcedureParameter(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"), rs.getInt("DATA_TYPE"), rs.getInt("COLUMN_TYPE"), rs.getString("TYPE_NAME"));
    System.out.println(param);
}
```

Retrieve something more meaningful than SQL Type ID 1111 ("Other") and Type Name "TABLE" (preferably sw_ty_number_array).

```
ProcedureParameter [parameterName=P_IN_NUM_PARAM, sqlType=3, parameterType=1, parameterTypeName=NUMBER]
ProcedureParameter [parameterName=P_IN_CHAR_PARAM, sqlType=12, parameterType=1, parameterTypeName=VARCHAR2]
ProcedureParameter [parameterName=P_IN_DATE_PARAM, sqlType=93, parameterType=1, parameterTypeName=DATE]
ProcedureParameter [parameterName=P_IN_ADT_PARAM, sqlType=1111, parameterType=1, parameterTypeName=TABLE]
ProcedureParameter [parameterName=P_OUT_NUM_PARAM, sqlType=3, parameterType=4, parameterTypeName=NUMBER]
ProcedureParameter [parameterName=P_OUT_CHAR_PARAM, sqlType=12, parameterType=4, parameterTypeName=VARCHAR2]
ProcedureParameter [parameterName=P_OUT_DATE_PARAM, sqlType=93, parameterType=4, parameterTypeName=DATE]
ProcedureParameter [parameterName=P_OUT_ADT_PARAM, sqlType=1111, parameterType=4, parameterTypeName=TABLE]
ProcedureParameter [parameterName=P_INOUT_NUM_PARAM, sqlType=3, parameterType=2, parameterTypeName=NUMBER]
ProcedureParameter [parameterName=P_INOUT_CHAR_PARAM, sqlType=12, parameterType=2, parameterTypeName=VARCHAR2]
ProcedureParameter [parameterName=P_INOUT_DATE_PARAM, sqlType=93, parameterType=2, parameterTypeName=DATE]
ProcedureParameter [parameterName=P_INOUT_ADT_PARAM, sqlType=1111, parameterType=2, parameterTypeName=TABLE]
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, we have been unable to find a working solution.

The current alternative is to query the view `user_arguments` and retrieve the data manually.