# Can I call a stored procedure in jdbc which returns a table using mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, return-value, stored-functions

I'm new to using jdbc to execute mysql stored procedures. My question is that is it possible to call an stored procedure which returns a table in jdbc?
I searched a lot and I know I can return a certain number of parameters using `registerOutParameter` using procedures, but how about a whole table with several rows?!

I hope it's not a redundant post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible to call a MySQL stored procedure to return a resultset using JDBC.

Examples provided here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#calling_javadb_mysql

Comment: It's also possible for a MySQL stored procedure to return *multiple* resultsets, and to iterate through the returned resultsets using JDBC.

Comment: how is it possible? I tried it now but it only returns just one row of the table? how should I iterate?