# Declare an OUT parameter through Java class

Tags: java, oracle, spring, stored-procedures

I have created a user type in oracle

```
create or replace type my_array_list 
is
table of 
varchar2(100);
```

Now i have written a procedure which has a output parameter like this :

```
   type my_list_rec IS record
   (
      best_friends my_array_list,
      good_friends my_array_list
   );


   type my_list_array is table of my_list_rec;

  procedure friends_diff_prc(my_name in varchar2,
                                     my_friend_list_o   out my_list_array ,
                                     rc_o                  out number);
```

Now i am calling this proc through my JAVA Class which is extending `StoredProcedure`.

```
// Declare output parameter
 declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(
                PropertiesReader
                        .getPropertyValue(FRIENDSConstants.GET_FRIEND_LIST_OUT),
                OracleTypes.ARRAY,"MYDB.MY_ARRAY_LIST"));
```

But when i am calling a proc , i am getting

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
```

Am i declaring an OUT Parameter correctly??
And how i can parse the contents of that output parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is strikingly confusing. You have purposefully named two types that are very different with very similar name:

- `my_array_list` is a `SQL` type: a nested table of VARCHAR2
- `my_list_array` is a `PL/SQL` type: a table of record of `my_array_list`

PL/SQL and SQL types are physically very different. For example, [PL/SQL types can't be accessed directly through `jdbc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399750/java-passing-array-in-oracle-stored-procedure).

Furthermore, the two types are logically very different: I can't see how you can imagine to map the first type to the second. The second type is a collection of objects of the first type, you will never be able to swap the two types, ever.

I suggest the following:

1. don't name types that are very different with confusingly similar name.
2. create a wrapper procedure with SQL Objects around your PL/SQL procedure to be able to call it from jdbc.
3. see this SO for an example of calling a procedure with a SQL table as an OUT parameter: [Fetch Oracle table type from stored procedure using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410452/fetch-oracle-table-type-from-stored-procedure-using-jdbc).

Comment: Can you tell us about your 2nd suggestion?

Comment: You can't call a procedure that has PLSQL types directly from java. So you either need to modify the procedure to take SQL types, or you can build a wrapper PLSQL procedure that will make the conversion. For example PL/SQL records would be converted to SQL Objects. In your case since you have a table of record of tables (ouch!), your wrapper could take two SQL arrays and make one table with one record of the two arrays for example.