# pass associative array to java in pl/sql

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have a Java function with input parameters (HashMap >String, String> header, String url)

And I want to use Java function in PL/SQL.

I read that the type compatible with PL/SQL is an associative array.

But I spend a lot of hours and I can't find the solution.

I create a package to call java function because in function in PL/SQL can not use associative arrays.

So:

**The package:**

```
create or replace PACKAGE            SOLICITUDES_HTTP AS
 TYPE map_varchar2 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(255);
        Function Solicitud_Http_get (header IN map_varchar2,
    url IN VARCHAR2) return VARCHAR2;
END SOLICITUDES_HTTP;
```

**COMPILE OK**

**The package body:**

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY SOLICITUDES_HTTP AS   
Function Solicitud_Http_get (header IN map_varchar2,
url IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'HTTP_Request.sendGet(java.util.HashMap,java.Lang.String) return java.lang.String';
END SOLICITUDES_HTTP;
```

**COMPILE FAILS**

```
Error(17,30): PLS-00999: restricción de implantación (puede ser temporal) INDEX TABLE BY CHAR/VARCHAR2 parameters are disallowed
```

Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Error is quiet clear. It says you cannot use associative array. Try with nested table.

Comment: But i want in Java a type like HashMap<String,String>

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731742/how-to-call-a-procedure-with-associative-arrays-in-oracle-from-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a PL/SQL associative array like that - instead use a collection and modify your Java code to take two String arrays: one of keys; and one of values:

```
CREATE TYPE StringList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255)
/

CREATE PACKAGE SOLICITUDES_HTTP AS
  FUNCTION Solicitud_Http_get(
    header_keys   IN StringList,
    header_values IN StringList,
    url           IN VARCHAR2
  ) return VARCHAR2;
END SOLICITUDES_HTTP;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY SOLICITUDES_HTTP AS
  FUNCTION Solicitud_Http_get(
    header_keys   IN StringList,
    header_values IN StringList,
    url           IN VARCHAR2
  ) return VARCHAR2
  IS LANGUAGE JAVA
    NAME 'HTTP_Request.sendGet(java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[],java.Lang.String) return java.lang.String';
END SOLICITUDES_HTTP;
/
```

Comment: Thank you,
Finally, i create two array for this, but type java.sql.array:

<code>create or replace Function Solicitud_Http_get (headerKeys IN StringList,
headerValues IN StringList,
url IN VARCHAR2) return VARCHAR2
IS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'HTTP_Request.sendGET(java.sql.Array,java.sql.Array,java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';</code>