# How do I call a PL/SQL procedure with associative arrays?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I am calling a PL/SQL procedure with an associative array as per the [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraint.htm#JJDBC28180).

However I am getting an exception `array bind type must match PL/SQL table row type` though I believe that is what I am passing.

Specifically, I have a table, PL/SQL package and JDBC code as follows:

---

### Table EMPLOYEE

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
(   
"EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"EMPLOYEE_NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
"EMPLOYEE_DEPT" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
);
```

---

### Package PKG_SP_EMPLOYEE

```
create or replace PACKAGE PKG_SP_EMPLOYEE
AS
TYPE tbl_employees_in
IS
TABLE OF EMPLOYEE%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE main(
    p_employee IN PKG_SP_EMPLOYEE.tbl_employees_in,
    x_status OUT VARCHAR 
);
END PKG_SP_EMPLOYEE;
```

---

### Package Body PKG_SP_EMPLOYEE

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PKG_SP_EMPLOYEE
AS

PROCEDURE main(
    p_employee IN PKG_SP_EMPLOYEE.tbl_employees_in,
    x_status OUT VARCHAR
    )
IS
BEGIN 
FOR i in 1..p_employee.count

    loop
    INSERT INTO "EMPLOYEE"
           (
           EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, 
           EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
           EMPLOYEE_DEPT
           )
    VALUES (
           p_employee(i).EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
           p_employee(i).EMPLOYEE_NAME,
           p_employee(i).EMPLOYEE_DEPT
           );

    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('Success');
    x_status  := 'Success';

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Failure');
        x_status  := 'Failure';           

END main;
END PKG_SP_EMPLOYEE;
```

---

### JDBC Code

```
Connection con= null;
OracleCallableStatement cstmt = null;

try {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@test.com:1521:TESTAD",
                    "user","password");

    cstmt = (OracleCallableStatement)con.prepareCall (
                "begin PKG_SP_EMPLOYEE.MAIN (?,?); end;"); 

    String[] values = { "1", "John Doe", "HR" };

    cstmt.setPlsqlIndexTable (1, values, values.length, values.length, OracleTypes.VARCHAR, 3);

    cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR); 

    cstmt.execute ();

//...
```

---

### Java Exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MAIN'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 43:
**PLS-00418: array bind type must match PL/SQL table row type**
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

After reviewing the [Oracle documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraint.htm#JJDBC28180) I see that Oracle JDBC drivers support PL/SQL Associative Arrays of VARCHAR and NUMBER types. Does this mean it won't support associate arrays of complex types as shown in my code?

Comment: Please explain what you tried to do to solve this problem. Don't just copy-paste your code and expect someone is going to do debug it all...

Comment: I tried to follow Oracle documentation here - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraint.htm#JJDBC28180. Its mentioned - Oracle JDBC drivers support PL/SQL Associative Arrays of VARCHAR and NUMBER types. Does it mean it won't support associate arrays of complex types as shown in my code ?

Comment: That's certainly the way I read it. I suggest that instead of trying to pass back a complex type, you should form something like a comma-separated values string from your data and return that, or something else similar. Best of luck.

Comment: Fixed the code formatting and added a question to the ...question.

Comment: You are correct--you are limited to simple arrays like `String[]` and `BigDecimal[]`. Would you be able to do what you need with simple arrays alone?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you use SQLData and OracleData per the docs, https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/Oracle-object-types.html#GUID-5905674A-A045-40B1-96DE-726761517D50.

You can start with a SQLData object representing the row type, then create the OracleData object for the array and Oracle will take care of the rest.

example EmpRow:

```
class EmpRow implements SQLData {
    private String employeeNumber;
    private String employeeName;
    private String employeeDept;
    
    // add getters/setters/construtor

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {

        employeeNumber = stream.readString();
        employeeName = stream.readString();
        employeeDept = stream.readString();

    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {

        stream.writeString(employeeNumber);
        stream.writeString(employeeName);
        stream.writeString(employeeDept);
    }
}
```

example call:

```
// values is the associative array.  The keys will need to be numbered 1, 2, ... consecutively.  
public void runProcedure(Map<Integer, EmpRow> values) {
    
    Connection conn = //get connection
    conn.prepareCall("begin PKG_SP_EMPLOYEE.MAIN (?,?); end;");
    conn.setObject(1, new OracleData() {
        
        @Override
        public Object toJDBCObject(Connection arg0) throws SQLException {
            
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return ((OracleConnection) arg0).createOracleArray("PKG_SP_EMPLOYEE.tbl_employees_in", values);
        }
    }); 

    conn.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR); 
    conn.execute ();
    
    // rest of procedure
}
```

Personally, I have a separate PlsqlArray class that implements OracleData with a constructor that passes in the type name and the values. I haven't tested with your particular example so let me know if anything is amiss.